# How to join a column from to another dataframe onto a specific column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

- Data-1: (product_id, ...)
- Data-2: (product_id, product_category, ...)

**Both of them have different columns and different shapes.** But I need product_category joined onto Data-1 the corresponding product_id.

Is there any quick way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `df1` is your df with product ids and extra columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'p_id': {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4},
        'p1_extra': {0:'x', 1:'x', 2:'x', 3:'x', 4:'x'}
        })
```

and `df2` is your df with product ids, descriptions, and extra columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'p_id': {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5},
        'p_desc': {0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:'e'},
        'p2_unwanted': {0:'x', 1:'x', 2:'x', 3:'x', 4:'x'}
        })
```

From my understanding you want to simply join `product_description` from `df2`, on to `df1`, obviously aligning it with the correct `product_id`?

In which case, to join the two in a way that you append the product description to `df1`, you can simply use pandas `merge()` functionality

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2[['p_id', 'p_desc']],  how='left', on='p_id')
```

The `how` clause is important, depending on what you want to achieve, in this case `left` preserves all data in `df1` and only adds `product_description` if it exists, else `NULL` value.  If you only want to maintain values which also have a `product_description`, then you can invoke `inner`.  Same syntax as SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What if the names of id columns in the data frames are different? Do I need to make them same?

Comment: If you're joining columns have different names, e.g. 'product_id' in `df1` and 'prod_id' in `df2`, you will need to specify `left_on` and `right_on` instead of just `on` as `on` assumes same name e.g.
`df_merged = df1.merge(df2[['prod_id', 'p_desc']], how='left', left_on='product_id', right_on='prod_id')`

Same general idea as an SQL JOIN i.e. `on a.column_name = b.column_name`

Pandas docs are great for this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Man, I was writing a column's name wrong the whole time... :) Thanks for the answer, very clean.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the sample code below.

```
df1
     product_id    PRICE
0    VW            4
1    Maruthi       2
2    Fiat          7

df2
     product_id     FUEL
0    VW            Petrol
1    Scoda         Diesel
2    Maruthi       Diesel
3    Fiat          Petrol

print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='product_id'))
     product_id     PRICE      FUEL
0    VW             4          Petrol
1    Maruthi        2          Diesel
2    Fiat           7          Petrol
```

Here, those rows will be dropped off which are not there in DF1.

Answer (score 0):

Data 1 can be df1.
Data 2 can be df2.

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['product_id'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['product_id'])

df1 = df2.drop('product_id', axis = 1)


df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)
```

This should align the product IDs of Data1 with the Product_category in Data2.

Comment: This is a risky approach, as it assumes that there are the same number of occurrences of `product_id` in each table.  However, if `df1` is a table of observations/occurrences, where the same ID can appear multiple times, whilst `df2` is a reference table, then this will not work.

Comment: @cvonsteg That is very true, if one has recurring IDs and the other doesn't this will not work at all. In all honesty I think this would be easier to do in Excel with VLOOKUP as it would eradicate that issue.